# Apply the_content filter to a custom field with multiple values

Tags: custom-field, filters, oembed

I have a custom meta box set up that allows users to paste the Youtube URL of a video so that it can be embedded into a post/page.

The meta box can be repeated so that a user can add as few or as many URL's as they wish so I'm using this code snippet to display each as a list item;

```
<?php
    $video = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube-url');
    foreach ($video as $vid) {
        echo '<li>'.$vid.'</li>';
    }
?>
```

Is there a way that I can run `the_content` filter on each individual list item so that I can make use of oEmbed that is shipped with Wordpress?

Or perhaps there's a more efficient way...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need to do use [`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters).

```
foreach ($video as $vid) {
    echo '<li>'.apply_filters('the_content',$vid).'</li>';
}
```

It *may* be more efficient to concatenate a string and then run the filter on the whole thing.

```
$lis = '';
foreach ($video as $vid) {
    $lis .= '<li>'.$vid.'</li>';
}
echo apply_filters('the_content',$lis);
```

I haven't benchmarked the one versus the other but given that the latter calls the filter once and the former many times, I'd bet on the latter.